# validates syntax in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, syntax

This is my model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                uniqueness: true
end
```

The author of Rails Tutorial Example said "**Curly braces are optional when passing hashes as the final argument in a method**", but here the `presence` validation is not final argument, but it can be used without curly braces and is valid code. The `format` validation of email attribute also works.
Anybody can explain me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:name, :presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }` *is* the last argument passed to `validates`, so you don't need curly braces for it.

A case where you *would* need curly braces would be if you were passing arguments *after* that hash:

```
validates { :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 } }, some_other_argument
```

Where `some_other_argument` here is some hypothetical argument that comes *after* the hash. To process this correctly you would need the curly braces around the hash.

Comment: You're welcome! Please mark it as the answer if you think it answered your question :)